# Share java classes between multiple classloaders

Tags: java, classloader

I have a use case where I need to dynamically load and share a predefined set of packages/classes between multiple classloaders. The goal is to increase overall performance every time we load a jar file.

We are trying to load and execute "apps". Each app contains our SDK libraries. Each app that is loaded is done so in it's own URLClassLoader to keep it isolated from other code as well as to prevent library version conflicts. Since our SDKs libraries are in each and every app, we would like to cache these specific sets of packages/classes so that the next time we load another app, all of the SDK classes do not need to be loaded again and thus removing this overhead.

Since we have several versions of our SDK out there, we are attempting to do this dynamically. Such that, when an app is loaded, we already know what version of the SDK it is. So we would like to have some implementation of a parent Classloader that is specific to this sdk version (we will call it the SDKCacheClassLoader). When the URLClassLoader (or some custom subclass of it) loads and recognizes a package/class from the sdk, we would like to forward that class to the shared parent SDKCacheClassLoader. Then, the next time we load another jar file with the URLClassLoader (setting SDKCacheClassLoader as the shared parent classloader), the parent should already have that class found and loaded from the last execution and the new jar file should not need to be scanned looking for the SDK classes again.

Anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this goal?

Also, to be clear, I do not need to share instantiated objects, just simply the class definition since I understand that the JVM considers the same classes loaded by 2 different class loaders as completely separate classes.